# Run SQL Server query by ClickOnce

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I have a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application with [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) technology. In my new update I should create some table and a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) in my client's database. I can't find anything about this. Is it possible? If yes, how? An example or tutorial would be so helpful. If no, what would an alternative suggestion be?

Comment: Please provide some additional information.  What language are you using (VB or C#?) Are you already able to establish a connection with your user's local DB?  What is the database engine?  All of this information is relevant to answering your question.

Comment: I'm using C# and yes all local DB has same connectionstring.database engin is SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

Comment: If you can execute SQL commands against the user's db, you can create tables and stored procedures.  Simply create a SQLCommand object, and pass in the SQL text to create the table and stored procedure.  Please not, you will probably still want to check and see if these db objects exist, before you execute the SQL code.  That, or be sure you remove the table and stored procedure before you execute the script again.

Comment: That is true,I'll do as you said.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have many users of the WPF app all connecting to a single database. If this is the case then you probably don't want to start running updates against a single database each time you launch the app.

As an alternative consider batching the database changes into a single script and finding a way of having it run *once* at the same time that you update the client deployment files.